# Kubeflow 1.0 on Kubernetes 1.16 - compatibility

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I'm puzzled with `Kubeflow` documentation on https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/k8s/overview/

At one point is says:

[image]

just later to show in table:
[image: print screen]

Which one is it then true?

**Is it compatible but not fully tested?**

Thanks!

Comment: Better to open an issue in github

Comment: I have an installing issue. Where do you find this compatibility table?

Answer (score 0):

Kubeflow 1.0 [is compatible with Kubernetes 1.16](https://github.com/kubeflow/website/pull/1933).